# MQ7 Flying Fish output format

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors

I am new to Arduino project. I used MQ7 flying fish sensor to sense the CO.

[image: Photo of MQ7 (top)]

[image: Photo of MQ7 (bottom)]

Ok now I connected everything as mentioned in various tutorials, such as [Arduino CO Monitor Using MQ-7 Sensor](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-CO-Monitor-Using-MQ-7-Sensor/).

Also wrote this code based on the following tutorial

```
const int mq7Pin=0;//the AOUT pin of the CO sensor goes into analog pin A0 of the arduino

int mq7value;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);//sets the baud rate
  pinMode(mq7Pin, INPUT); 
}

void Heat(){
  Serial.println("Heating sensor");
  analogWrite(mq7Pin,255);
  delay(60000);
  Serial.println("Reducing the voltage");
  analogWrite(mq7Pin,71); //HIGH*1.4v/5v => 255*1400/5000
  delay(90000);
}

void Read(){
  mq7value=analogRead(mq7Pin);
}

void Print(){
  Serial.print("CO : ");
  Serial.println(mq7value);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Heat();
  Read(); 
  Print();
  delay(60000);
}
```

After this I got the following output:

```
Heating sensor

Reducing the voltage

CO : 82

Heating sensor

Reducing the voltage

CO : 246
```

I used the sensor in a hall and I got `82` in clean air.

After that I used smokes from incense sticks, and I got `246` as sensor value.

So my question is in what format did sensor returned these values? Are they in PPM format?

If not, how can I convert it?

Comment: Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-7.pdf), The output is logarithmic to the PPM. But you'd need to calibrate the outputs first, to get a accurate PPM value. I'm also not sure what the potentiometer and opamp(?) on that breakout are doing.

Comment: Sir any resources on how to calculate it. Most of the tutorial I saw prints  sensor value as ppm.

Comment: The link that you provided demonstrates/explains how to calibrate/adjust the voltage to PPM

Comment: I suspect some tutorials just slap a "ppm" after the value, and call it a day.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was confused with various tutorial saying the value was ppm. I know it was not that simple. And I also many tutorial with different kind of ppm calculation formula. Thank you for solving this confusion.